# Allegedly legible lexical ledger

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

Can you figure out what's going on here?

```
    **********
           - D
  ------------
     *********
           + O
  ------------
    **********
           - W
  ------------
     *********
           + T
  ------------
    **********
           + E
  ------------
   ***********
           - O
  ------------
    **********
           - A
  ------------
     *********
           + P
  ------------
    **********
           - N
  ------------
     *********
           + C
  ------------
    **********
           - G
  ------------
     *********
           + O
  ------------
    **********
           - P
  ------------
     *********
           + S
  ------------
    **********
           - O
  ------------
     *********
           + D
  ------------
    **********
           - C
  ------------
     *********
           + P
  ------------
    **********
           - T
  ------------
     *********
           + G
  ------------
    **********
           - P
  ------------
     *********
           + A
  ------------
    **********
           - G
  ------------
     *********
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like

> each set of stars should be a word, and adding or removing the given letters should lead to a new word (possibly with anagramming?).

Using that, we can start filling things in:

> Based on letters that are removed before they're added, the first string must have D, W, A, N, G, and five unknown letters. Those five letters stay the whole way through, so they should be reasonably common.
>
>   After throwing those letters [into Qat](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=%2Fdwang.....&ent=Search&dict=0) and trying a few options, I hit on `WANDERINGS` as a workable one -- that makes the extra letter set `ERINS`, which are all very common.

So the filled chart is:

> (There are a few options for some of these - I've just arbitrarily chosen one.)
>        `WANDERINGS`
>  `[-D]   ANSWERING`
>  `[+O]  NORWEGIANS`
>  `[-W]   REASONING`
>  `[+T]  RESONATING`
>  `[+E] GENERATIONS`
>  `[-O]  TANGERINES`
>  `[-A]   RESENTING`
>  `[+P]  PRESENTING`
>  `[-N]   PESTERING`
>  `[+C]  RESPECTING`
>  `[-G]   PRESCIENT`
>  `[+O]  RECEPTIONS`
>  `[-P]   SECRETION`
>  `[+S]  SECRETIONS`
>  `[-O]   SINCEREST`
>  `[+D]  DIRECTNESS`
>  `[-C]   DISSENTER`
>  `[+P]  PRESIDENTS`
>  `[-T]   DISPENSER`
>  `[+G]  DEPRESSING`
>  `[-P]   REDESIGNS`
>  `[+A]  REASSIGNED`
>  `[-G]   READINESS`

Comment: The fifth operation is +E, not -E, so a possible word would be rot13(TRARENGVBAF) instead of rot13(VTABENAGF)

Comment: @samm82 Fixed, thank you!

Comment: Thank you for explaining your reasoning and describing how you surmised the first word.  I worked hard on coming up with a chain that was interesting and also offered enough clues to determine the first word.